# What is the correct UML relationship between a Stack and SubClasses?

Tags: c++, uml

I've looked around for a while trying to figure out what the correct relationship is between a Stack and SubClasses is for this kind of implementation:

```
struct Animal {
    virtual void feed() = 0;
};

struct Dog : Animal {
    void feed() {
        cout << "bark";
    }
};

struct Cat : Animal {
    void feed() {
        cout << "meow";
    }
};

struct AnimalStack {
    Animal *array[10];

    //rest of implementation for the stack
};

int main() {
    //create Stack
    //create new Animal objects and push them to the AnimalStack
}
```

I think the relationship between Stack and Animal is an associative one, but I've also seen someone argue for a dependency relationship for a similar problem.

Comment: As a bit of a sidenote, I think `Stack` is a very bad name for a Stack of Animals as it will be understood as some kind of generic stack of things, whereas this is a very specific kind of Stack. I would use `AnimalStack` or something similar.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just came up with a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an example of *aggregation*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation

- The Stack has Animals
- There is no stated ownership

The argument of a dependency relation is a weak one and does not suggest that the Stack stores the (pointers to) Animals. It does not describe the code in a meaningful way.

The fact that *Animal* has subclasses is a separate part of the model and does not change the Stack -> Animal relationship.